Time complexity beyond recursive functions
Ordinary time complexity definitions require the problem/function to be computable.  However, it appears there are natural notions of computational time complexity for arbitrary hyperarithmetic problems, and beyond.  I will explain below, but my questions are:

Have similar notions of time complexity for uncomputable problems been studied before?
How far (in terms of descriptive set theory) can we define natural reasonable time complexity notions?
Do we get sufficient no-speed-up results, such as an arithmetic decision problem has polynomial time complexity iff it is in P ?

The only recursive decision problems polynomial time computable for the below notions are those in $P$, simply because the oracles are uncomputably sparse.  (However, the oracles are not low for speed, as used in the literature, because from $0'$ we get sufficiently pseudorandom data.)
$Δ^0_2$ problems
For problems computable from the halting problem, we can ask for their time complexity given an oracle for a busy beaver function $B$.  This limits the speed up for recursive functions, and also roughly corresponds to when a computable process can correctly guess the answers.  The busy beaver function is affected by the choice of representation, but we get independence-of-representation by using adversarially selected $B'$, with $∃c \, ∀n \, B(n) ≤ B'(n) ≤ B(n^c)$.  Time complexity $B(n^{O(1)})$ would mean an algorithm that for every $B'$ works in $B(n^{O(1)}$) time.  (Whether some decision problems not in P have $n^{O(1)}$ complexity is part of the question; note that an above $c$ is not disclosed.)
The independence of representation affects the precision with which we can state the complexity, but using compact representations, we can reduce $n^{O(1)}$ to $n+O(\log n)$ ($n$ is the number of bits).  For $n+O(1)$, I think there are inequivalent (for our purposes) choices of busy beaver, including the regular (the usual one), prefix-free (binary alphabet), autohalt-on-input-end (binary alphabet), and (see $B_0$ below) Chaitin's constant based.
Hyperarithmetic problems
We will use a sequence of busy-beaver-like functions, adjusted to get representation independence; one function per Turing jump.
Fix an ordinal notation system for a limit ordinal.  Fix an oracle universal Turing machine $U$; the choice of $U$ will not affect the complexity notion.  Let $B_α(n) = \min(t:P_∞ - P_t < 2^{-n})$ where $P_t$ is halting probability for $t$ steps using $U$, (the notation for) $α$ and $0^{(α)}$ ($α$th Turing jump of 0) oracle, and random data.
An adversary gives $B'$ such that $∃c ∀α ∀n \, B_α(n) ≤ B'_α(n) ≤ B_α(n+B_{α+2}(c))$ (unless we want to give the adversary a different amount of leeway), and an algorithm must work for all adversaries.
The use of $B_{α+2}(c)$ rather than $c$ is to give independence from the ordinal notation system (for the same ordinal); converting $α$ to a different system is $Δ^0_{α+3}$ (but converting $0^{(α)}$ oracle is not otherwise a problem).  The impact of $B_{α+2}(c)$ rather than $c$ on complexity is minor, as typically either $α$ is constant or $α+O(1)$ in place of $α$ is good enough.  If desired (but this affects the complexity notion), it can be mitigated by using $B_{α+2}(c)$ for additively indecomposable ordinals, $B_{α+1}(c)$ for their successors, and $c$ for other ordinals, and we can reduce this further by imposing conditions on ordinal notation systems.
Beyond hyperarithmetic
To get all true $Π^1_1$ statements, we could allow all ordinal notation systems and adjust the adversary appropriately, but the simplest change is to use a recursive pseudowellordering; its choice will not affect the complexity.  $B_x$ will be defined for well-founded $x$, while for ill-founded $x$, $B'_x(n)>m$ query will always return true (note that this does not allow confirming that $x$ is ill-founded).
For zero hyperjump (or Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$), we have an analog of Chaitin's constant:  Probability that the above $U$ (or another suitable Turing machine; no oracles besides random data) outputs a code for a recursive well-ordering and stops.  We assign the halting time to be $B'_α(0)$ where $α$ is the ordinal whose code was output (i.e. the length of the well-ordering), and define $B$ and $B'$ accordingly.  The complexity notion is unaffected by any assignment of halting times that is between $B'_α(0)$ and for example $B'_{α+ω}(c+\text{actual_halting_time})$, but note that we use $B'$ rather than $B$.  To go beyond, we can iterate the construction and the hyperjump.  Note that there are oracle Turing machines that for every oracle $A$ implement an $A$-(recursive pseudowellordering).

Correction:  The failure of low-for-speed here is analogous to Blum's speedup theorem rather than due to pseudorandomness.

Moschovakis' notion of a computation theory might be relevant here; cf. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0049237X0871231X. These is an axiomatic treatment of higher recursion theory in which (ordinal) length of a computation is a primitive notion.
